# readClipboard removed from utils package?

Tags: r, installation, package, version, clipboard

I'm using R 3.1.0 and can't seem to find the readClipboard function that should be in the utils package. Is there a way to enable the use that function from an older package?

Thanks.

Comment: Which operating systems are you using?  This function is only available in Windows, AFAIK.  If this was removed from R, there is no mention in [NEWS.R-devel](http://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/NEWS.R-devel.html)

Comment: Good point! I'm using 3.2.0 on linux. Is there an equivalent function for linux?

Comment: How are you running 3.2? The current version is 3.1. Are you running a daily snapshot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`read.DIF("clipboard")` will do the same job. try that. I think it is possible however to integrate old utils packages. You can download and install them from [here](http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/utils/download.packages)

Comment: Thanks! Is there a specific reason why the function was removed?

Comment: @user3003082 i dunno why unfortunately. If the answer works please click the tick beside it :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you may be after:

```
readLines("clipboard")
```

However, for an OS independent approach see this GitHub package, [overflow's](https://github.com/sebastian-c/overflow), [readClip](https://github.com/sebastian-c/overflow/blob/master/R/readClip.R) function.

Answer (score 0):

You can also read from the clipboard with `read.table` and `read.csv`

```
read.table("clipboard", ...)
## or
read.csv("clipboard", ...)
```

[This link](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Data_input_and_output/Loading_and_storing_data_with_the_keyboard_and_clipboard) has proven useful for me over time.