# Why read.clipboard is not working in R

Tags: linux, r

Why is read.clipboard() not working on my system?

```
> library(psych)
> read.table(text=read.clipboard(), sep="\t", header=T, stringsAsFactors=F, strip.white=T)  
Error in textConnection(text, encoding = "UTF-8") : 
  invalid 'text' argument
In addition: Warning message:
In read.table(file("clipboard"), header = TRUE, ...) :
  incomplete final line found by readTableHeader on 'clipboard'


> read.table(text=readClipboard(), sep="\t", header=T, stringsAsFactors=F, strip.white=T)  
Error in textConnection(text, encoding = "UTF-8") : 
  could not find function "readClipboard"
```

The version information:

```
> packageVersion('psych')
[1] ‘1.4.8.11’


> R.version
               _                           
platform       i486-pc-linux-gnu           
arch           i486                        
os             linux-gnu                   
system         i486, linux-gnu             
status                                     
major          3                           
minor          1.1                         
year           2014                        
month          07                          
day            10                          
svn rev        66115                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 3.1.1 (2014-07-10)
nickname       Sock it to Me               
>
```

EDIT:

As suggested by @RichardScriven, I used following:

```
read.table('clipboard', sep="\t", header=T)
```

If I copy some cells in a spreadsheet and try above command, it does not work. Following is the error:

```
Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, "rt") : clipboard cannot be opened or contains no text
```

But if I paste first to a text editor, and copy it again from there, then the above command works well.

How can I directly use the data after copying from a spreadsheet?

Following command also shows same problem, works when copied from text editor but not when copied from spreadsheet. I produces same error.

```
> read.clipboard(sep="\t", header=T)  
Error in open.connection(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In open.connection(file, "rt") :
  clipboard cannot be opened or contains no text
```

Comment: `readClipboard` is only available on Windows I think.  But you can try `overflow::readClip` for a non-system dependent clipboard reader.  See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24365249/readclipboard-removed-from-utils-package).   You can also do `read.table("clipboard", ...)`

Comment: You may be right as it is working on a windows R version which I can run on my Linux system using 'wine' Linux package.

Comment: [This link](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Data_input_and_output/Loading_and_storing_data_with_the_keyboard_and_clipboard/) is also useful

Comment: Doesn't `read.table("clipboard",...)` work for you?

Comment: Please see edit in my question above.

Comment: why are you doing read.clipboard inside read.table? you should be doing `dat <- read.clipboard(other args, ...)`

Comment: Same problem -see my edit above.

Comment: just tested with excel on osx and works fine

Comment: FWIW, I tested opening an `.ods` document and it worked. What kind of spreadsheet are you using?

Comment: I am using libreoffice 3.5.4.2 on Debian Stable Linux.

Comment: @nicola : you opened .ods document on which system?

Comment: As suggested by @rawr above; works fine copying from libreOffice on Ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

read.clipboard(sep="\t",header = T)
The above code should work. Also please note that you need to copy [from excel / libreoffice etc] , go to R script and run the command in R. If you perform any other commands in between, this might not work. Hope this helps.